# Using the preposition "in" with gehen in a dative case?

Tags: grammatical-case

I got a bit confused when I read this sentence:

> Nach  der  Apfelweinkneipe  sind  Christa  und  ich  in der  Frankfurter  Altstadt  spazieren gegangen.

Since the noun *Altstadt* is feminine and we're using the verb *gehen* with the two-way preposition *in* to describe we're going to somewhere, shouldn't *Altstadt* come in the accusative case?

I think in this sentence it'd be ok to use the dative case with another verb while using *in*:

> Nach der Apfelweinkneipe machten Christa und ich einen Spaziergang in der Frankfurter Altstadt.

Comment: Youre *not* going to the Altstadt. "spazierengehen" implies that you went there, looked around, and eventually came back. Thus it's not the goal of a one-way trip, but the location of an extended activity.

Comment: The Apfelweinkneipe is already in the Frankfurter Altstadt, they didn't have to go there, they were already there, which explains the dative

Comment: "in der ..." says where the activity took place. "in die .." says to which destination they went in order to do this. In the context of "spazieren gehen" I would prefer "in der".